# Mahout: Importing CSV file to Sequence Files using regexconverter or arff.vector

Tags: mahout

I just started learning how to use mahout. I'm not a java programmer however, so I'm trying to stay away from having to use the java library.

I noticed there is a shell tool regexconverter. However, the documentation is sparse and non instructive. Exactly what does specifying a regex option do, and what does the transformer class and formatter class do? [The mahout wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/file-format-integrations.html) is marvelously opaque. I'm assuming the regex option specifies what counts as a "unit" or so.

The example they list is of using the regexconverter to convert http log requests to sequence files I believe. I have a csv file with slightly altered http log requests that I'm hoping to convert to sequence files. Do I simply change the regex expression to take each entire row? I'm trying to run a Bayes classifier, similar to the [20 newsgroups example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Twenty+Newsgroups) which seems to be done completely in the shell without need for java coding.

Incidentally, the [arff.vector](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/creating-vectors-from-wekas-arff-format.html) command seems to allow me to convert an arff file directly to vectors. I'm unfamiliar with arff, thought it seems to be something I can easily convert csv log files into. Should I use this method instead, and skip the sequence file step completely?

Thanks for the help.